# How to show that $\mathbb{P}^2$ blowing up at a point is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1*\mathbb{P}^1$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, blowup

I know that  $\mathbb{P}^2$ blowing up at two points is isomorphic to  $\mathbb{P}^1*\mathbb{P}^1$ blowing up at one point, so why $\mathbb{P}^2$ blowing up at a point is not isomorphic to  $\mathbb{P}^1*\mathbb{P}^1$?
and is $\mathbb{P}^2$ blowing up at one point not isomorphic to  $\mathbb{P}^2$ blowing up at another point? I think the answer is no but I don't know why.

Comment: You have some misunderstanding. Blowing up 2 points in the plane is NOT isomorphic to product of lines. You will have to blow down the proper transform of the line joining the two points to get product of two lines.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\Proj}{\mathbf{P}}$I assume you're working over the complex numbers.

- Because the projective plane $\Proj^{2}$ is homogeneous, the blow-up of $\Proj^{2}$ at a point $p$ does not depend, up to isomorphism, on the choice of $p$.
- The blow-up of $\Proj^{2}$ at one point has an exceptional divisor with self-intersection $-1$. No curve in $\Proj^{1} \times \Proj^{1}$ has self-intersection $-1$.
- A rational map $\Proj^{2} \to \Proj^{1} \times \Proj^{1}$ can be defined by picking two points $p \neq q$, blowing up at $p$ and $q$, then blowing down the proper transform of the line $\overline{pq}$.

The diagrams below show the respective surfaces with embedded rational curves and their self-intersection numbers; dots indicate points being blown up. (You can think of these pictures as metaphorical, or as the literal images of moment maps for real $2$-torus actions. In that case, if you want to nitpick, the diagonal edge in the upper-left diagram should have slope $-1$.)

The standard algebro-geometric rational map from $\Proj^{1} \times \Proj^{1} \to \Proj^{2}$ should be mentioned: Consider a smooth quadric surface $Q \simeq \Proj^{1} \times \Proj^{1}$ in $\Proj^{3}$. Pick a point $q$ of $Q$ and a plane $H \simeq \Proj^{2}$ not containing $q$. Projection away from $q$ defines a map $Q \setminus\{q\} \to H$ that collapses two lines, the rulings of $Q$ through $q$, and is otherwise bijective (since every line through $q$ that is not a ruling hits $Q$ in exactly one other point). This map is well-defined on the blow-up of $Q$ at $q$. That is, blowing up the quadric at one point then blowing down two points gives $H$.

[image: Rational equivalence of the projective plane and a product of projective lines]

Answer (score 0):

Over the complex numbers, you can compute their Euler characteristics as manifolds. The euler characteristic of $Bl_p P^2$ is 4 (I will explain below). The euler characteristic of $P^1 \times P^1$ is 5 - this comes from computing the cohomology grups via Kunneth. Thus they cannot be even homeomorphic (in the classical topology). Note that an isomorphism of varieties will induce a homeomorphism in the classical topology.

To see that the Euler characteristic of $Bl_p P^2$ is 4, think about the blow up as removing a point and replacing it with a $S^2$. This total change in Euler characteristic is 1, so $\chi(P^2) + 1 = 3 + 1 = 4$. I'm not completely sure how to formalize this (other than "integrating against the euler charactersitic", which you can see here for: A.G. Khovanskii and A.V. Pukhlikov, Integral transforms based on Euler
characteristic and their applications ). You can also tediously show that the plane blown up at a point is a Hirzebruch surface, and then refer to here: http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Hirzebruch_surfaces

Double check my computations?

Maybe a similar argument works in positive characteristic?

Edit: As Mariano points out, one can do this computation with Mayer-Vietoris. That is, we want to know $\chi(Bl_0(\mathbb{C}^2))$, and there is a natural deformation retraction between the blow up of the affine plane at a point and the $\mathbb{CP}^1$ of lines through $0$. A little more explicitly, we fix the exceptional divisor and for $t \in (0,1]$ send $v \in C^2 \setminus p$ to $tv$, and in the limit send it to the line spanned by $v$.

From here we can use inclusion exclusion for the Euler characteristic (which is what Mayer Vietoris implies for Euler characteristic): Taking $U$ to an $A^2$ neigborhood of $p$ and $V = P^2 \setminus p$, $Blp P^2 = (Bl_p U) \cup V$, $Bl_pU \cap V = U \cap V$. So $\chi(P^2) = \chi(U) + \chi(V) - \chi(U \cap V) = \chi(Bl_p U) - 1 + \chi(V) - \chi(U \cap V) = \chi(Bl_p P^2) - 1$. (This works in general for blowing up a smooth variety at a point.)

Comment: To formalize that, do Mayer-Vietoris.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks :)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Does it also work for blowing up a smooth variety Y along a smooth subvariety X? The new Euler characteristic is obtained by adding the difference $\chi(E) - \chi(X) = \chi(X)*2(c - 1) - \chi(X)$, where E is the exceptional divisor $c$ is the codimension of X in Y / rank of the normal bundle? (So $2(c - 1)$ is the Euler characteristic of the fibers of the blow up over X.) (You'd take a tubular neighborhood of X and cover it by patches that deformation retract onto X, correspondingly the blow up  in the neighborhood at X, then apply the same computation as in my edit...)

Comment: The Euler characteristic of $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ is actually 4 - so this argument doesn't quite work.